# Static member 'currency' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'SomeProtocol.Type'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I will give you some context first. I'm trying to make a function that takes as a parameter any type that conforms to a protocol (SomeProtocol). So, I created a struct with static method called currency and this struct conforms to SomeProtocol, but, I'm getting this error when trying to pass the method as argument for that generic function: "Static member 'currency' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'SomeProtocol.Type'".

I'm just trying to recreate this SwiftUI code:

`Text(20.0, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))`

Reading the documentation, the function from above is a generic init() that takes a generic type that conforms to some protocols.

`init<F>(_ input: F.FormatInput, format: F) where F : FormatStyle, F.FormatInput : Equatable, F.FormatOutput == String`

So, `.currency()` is a static method that comes from `FloatingPointFormatStyle.Currency`, a `struct`that conforms to `FormatStyle`.

My question is, why is this working in SwiftUI (passing a static method from a struct that conforms to a protocol as an argument to a function that accepts any type that conforms to that protocol) but is not in my own example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype SomeType: SomeProtocol
    var a: String { get }
    var b: String { get }
    static func currency(x: Int) -> SomeType
}

func someTest<T>(x: T) -> String where T: SomeProtocol{
    return "this works!"
}

struct AnotherType: SomeProtocol {
    let a = "Test"
    let b = "someTest"

    static func currency(x: Int) -> AnotherType {
        return AnotherType()
    }
}

someTest(x: .currency(x: 20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.currency(...)` is an [implicit member expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Implicit-Member-Expression).

> An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an enumeration case or a type method, in a context where type inference can determine the implied type.

Swift only knows that the parameter `x` expects some `SomeProtocol` type, but doesn't know which one. So it thinks that you mean:

```
someTest(x: SomeProtocol.currency(x: 20))
```

This is invalid. Which implementation's `currency` are you calling? The `currency` method declared in `SomeProtocol` has no implementation!

You can only call `currency` on specific implementations of the protocol, e.g. `AnotherType.currency(x: 20)`.

Notice that the documentation for the builtin [`currency`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/floatingpointformatstyle/3870081-currency) doesn't say anything like "Required", or "Default implementation provided". What SwiftUI does is make an extension of the protocol that contains the implementation of `currency`, instead of making a protocol requirement:

```
extension SomeProtocol {
    static func currency(x: Int) -> AnotherType {
        return AnotherType()
    }
}
```

But this is still not enough though. You still cannot do `SomeProtocol.currency(...)`. What if `currency` uses some static requirements of the protocol? Swift doesn't know whether there is any, or whether `currency` uses them.

So you actually need:

```
extension SomeProtocol where Self == AnotherType {
    static func currency(x: Int) -> AnotherType {
        return AnotherType()
    }
}
```

Now Swift knows that `.currency(x: 20)` means `AnotherType.currency(x: 20)`.

Note that the `SomeType` associated type is unnecessary. You can add further constraints involving that if you want, but it is not necessary for this kind of implicit member expression to work.

Comment: @DiegoPerdomo No...? The `Self` requirement is just a way to help Swift find the type that should be inserted before the `.`. Whether the function is generic doesn't matter. This is probably not how SwiftUI does it, but you can make `Self == SomeRandomFormatStyle` and still declare `static func foo<V>() -> FloatingPointFormatStyle<V>.Currency where V: BinaryFloatingPoint`.

Comment: Thanks again, everything is clear now, I got confused because we were specific here with the "Self ==" but that was only for the "dot syntax" to work and has nothing to do with the generic function.

Comment: Only for clarification and in case some other people are curious as me and want to know more: actually yes, SwiftUI does a lot of protocol extensions for a lot of different types apart from "Currency", we can see the docs were they say: "Available when Self is "ABC" type. So, I didn't ask the last question in the correct way, I was asking if Apple does protocol extensions anytime they want to implement this kind of functionality like the .currency() method) and yes, they do. At least for the FormatStyle protocol they have a lot of extensions.